React Native Wifi reborn (WifiManager) issue on iOS (working fine on Android)
I am using the react-native-wifi-reborn library to connect to a Wifi Network from the App without going into Wifi Settings. The code is working fine on android but on IOS it gives an error:
"
Argument 4 (NSNumber) of WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID is marked as nullable but React requires that all NSNumber arguments are explicitly marked as nonnull to ensure compatibility with Android.
"
ERROR SS
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, Alert, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import WifiManager from 'react-native-wifi-reborn';

const WifiScreen = () => {
 
  const ssid = '';
  const password = '';

  const connectToWifi = async () => {
    await WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID(ssid, password, false, true);
    console.log(`Connected to Wi-Fi: ${ssid}`);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Connect to Local Network</Text>
      <Button title="Connect to Wi-Fi" onPress={connectToWifi} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

export default WifiScreen;

